# How to shard existing key-value storage?

Tags: scalability, redis, key-value-store

Let's suppose that we have 3Gb key-value storage on server A. I'm starting to feel that we need another server (server B). So, I have to separate server A data over shards (server A, server B), but... All keys on server A currently represented as is (for example, `comment_ids:user_id:10`).

Question #1: What is the best practice to hash current key names and separate all data over shards?

Question #2: What is the best practice of adding additional servers to shard's row?

PS: Sorry for my English, but I hope that my answer is clear for you.

Thank you.

PS: I've marked this question with `redis` tag, but really it's not about redis at all, but all key-value storages.

Comment: Sure, I'm always interested in answers!

Answer (score 0):

Consistent hashing tends to be a good choice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing